# How to properly instantiate inner classes through reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following line of code in a top level module:

```
String username = "testuser987-abc-zyx@gmail.com"
ModelBuilder userBuilder = utilityManager.getUtility("user").generateBuilder(username);
```

Inside my "user" utility class I have the following:

```
private class UserBuilder extends ModelBuilder {
    private final String username;

    public UserBuilder(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public User execute() {
        return populateUserInformation(username);
    }
}

@Override
public UserBuilder generateBuilder(Object... arguments) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    try {
        return UserBuilder.class.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance((String) arguments[0]);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException e) {
        throw new ReflectiveOperationException(e);
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the generateBuilder(Object... arguments) method to return a new instance of my UserBuilder class (as a ModelBuilder), however, when I run the code I get the following exception:

```
nested exception is java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:   
com.login.util.UserOperationsUtility$UserBuilder.<init>(java.lang.String)] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.login.util.UserOperationsUtility$UserBuilder.<init>(java.lang.String)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
```

I tried to follow the java docs for Constructor, but I'm not sure how to debug this. My knowledge of Java's reflective capabilities is pretty small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is explicitly specified in the [`getConstructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) documentation:

> If this `Class` object represents an inner class declared in a non-static context, the formal parameter types include the explicit enclosing instance as the first parameter.

This is the case, you have an inner, non-`static` class. Indeed you would need to qualify the instantiation of an `UserBuilder` object through an instance of the enclosing class also at compile time, that's the case also when using reflection. You have two choices:

- make the `class` static
- lookup the correct constructor and pass the enclosing instance

The latter is easily done:

```
Constructor c = UserBuilder.class.getConstructor(UserOperationsUtility.class, String.class);
return c.newInstance(this, (String)args[0]);
```